# Problems Implmenting Widget Android Studio - AsynTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, widget, android-widget

I'm new programming with Android Studio. In my *MainActivity.java* I call to ReadPage class, that extends from AsyncTask (to could read a web page in a JSON format) where I overrides *doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute*; until here, the app is working great.

But, I would like to implement a widget *AppWidget.java* in order to could read the same page in JSON format and print the given information in the widget fields. Due to *ReadPage* class is defined into *MainActivity.java*, I wrote a *ReadPageWidget* function that is almost the same function, but I can't implement it and let it working:

In *AppWidget.java*, I understand that in my *onUpdate* function I have to invocate `new ReadPageWidget(views).execute("Updating")` and then `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);` where views was defined previously like `RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);`

In my widget I would like to have a button that on pressed, it updates the information from the web page, so I defined a `function public void UpdateDate(View view)`.

I don't know how to implement this widget and, all the proobs that I do, finishes forcing the close of the application.

Edited:
According to the basic example of creating widgets, I have defined the `onUpdate` function like this:

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
            SimpleDateFormat Date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss aa");
            String DateFormat = Date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.TVUpdatingDate, DateFormat);
            new ReadPageWidget(views).execute("Updating");
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In this, I created the instance of ReadPageWidget and execute the AsynTask, using the parameter `views`. Only when I run the application, the field `DateFormat` is updated, in spite of I have defined `android:updatePeriodMillis="3000"` into my `app_widget_info.xml`

My `app_widget.xml` is defined like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Field"
        android:id="@+id/FieldJSON"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="UpdatingDate"
        android:id="@+id/BUpdatingDate"
        android:onClick="UpdateDate"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

where `FieldJSON` should be updated by the widget with the `ReadPageWidget` function.

The only differences between ReadPage and ReadPageWidget are in definition of attributes and the constructor method:

```
public class ReadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    MainActivity Context;
    ProgressBar ProgressBarReadPage;
    TextView TVPage;

    public ReadPage(MainActivity Context) {
        this.Context = Context;
    }

    ...
}
```

vs

```
public class ReadPageWidget extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private RemoteViews views;

    public ReadPageWidget(RemoteViews views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
}
```

Edited:

I have added the `onclick` function in the `button` BUpdatingDate and UpdateDate function in AppWidget.java:

```
public void UpdateDate(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(view.getContext());
    ComponentName thisAppWidgetComponentName = new ComponentName(view.getContext().getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidgetComponentName);
    this.onUpdate(view.getContext(), appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Comment: So you want to create a widget that which will be updated by the json ? Have you implement it to share it with us?

Comment: I have added some specifications basics of the implemented, thanks

Comment: and one last thing, where onUpdate is located in your activity or fragment?

Comment: It's in my AppWidget class (edited)

Answer (score 1):

What I think is Happened here is because of not calling the onUpdate fun in a right place :

for updating UI you should put all ui related updating in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask

and calling apis and getting JSONs are in doInBackGround() of AsyncTask

Comment: I have edited my question (I added the section where I call the onUpdate function); but I don't know how to pass the parameters needed

Comment: in on Click you should put the AsyncTask with the update function in onPostExecute(), so when the doInBackground finished the update function will be called in onPostExecute an you will see the result on View

Comment: My doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute functions is the same that the functions in ReadPage class. I updated the UpdateDate function in the question with new call of onUpdate function, but it stills not working

Comment: I can't do this even, in spite of your help